# How to change url with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would change the src value with a variable in order to have a channel list to be selected, I thought of a php file but do not know how to set it, to pass a url to the script

```
src: 'http://example.com/streaming/password/playlist.m3u8'
```

it's possible to do it?

```
    <script>
        flowplayer('#player', {
          ratio: 0.4167,
          background: true,
          //splash: true,
          clip: {
            title: 'Background video',
            sources: [{
              type: 'application/x-mpegurl',
              src: 'http://example.com/streaming/password/playlist.m3u8'
            }, {
              type: 'video/webm',src: '//stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.webm'
        }, {
          type: 'video/mp4',
          src: '//stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4'
        }]
      }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a PHP question, it's a Javascript or Jquery, you might want to update your tags

Comment: `src: '<?php echo $var?>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `src` of an element with jQuery. Like this

```
var source = clip.sources.source;
$('#idOfYourElement').attr("src", source);
```